# Convert js stringified string to multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

I get this kind of string from JS to PHP.
[[1,"10.00","10.00","A"],[2,"20.00","25.00","B"],[3,"10.00","25.00","C"],[6,"10.00","25.00","D"]]

**How can I convert it to a php multidimensional array?**

Note:
I tried json_encode without getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string = '[[1,"10.00","10.00","A"],[2,"20.00","25.00","B"],[3,"10.00","25.00","C"],[6,"10.00","25.00","D"]]';

$result = json_decode($string);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

You should use `json_decode` instead of `json_encode` for convert JSON to array PHP

Result:
[image: Ressult]